# RemoteWeb Driver driver not initializing because param-value-not-found

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I am trying to run some basic tests using Selenium Grid and I acquired the code below from my instructor.

However *RemoveWebDriver* *driver* is always NULL as *device* is always *param-value-not-found*

I am unable to understand what is setting the value of the parameter device and how to correct this error.

My knowledge of TestNG is limited. I am guessing TestNG is responsible for calling the openBrowser function which has a parameter device the value of this parameter is always param-value-not-found.

Therefore in the if else block device does not equal **pc1** or **pc2** which causes driver vairable to have a value Null.

I am unable to figure out how the value of device is getting derived.

```
    
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    public class gridTest
    {
    
    public static WebDriver driver ;
    
    @Parameters("System")
    @Test(priority=0)
    public void openBrowser(String device) throws MalformedURLException // device is always param-value-not-found
    {
    System.out.println("device is : " + device); 
    
    if (device.equalsIgnoreCase("pc1"))
    {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setCapability("browserVersion", "80");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.6:30032/wd/hub"), cap);
    }
    else if (device.equalsIgnoreCase("pc2"))
    {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.6:30032/wd/hub"), cap);
    
    // adding the following else block merely bypasses the issue
    } else {
    String nodeUrl = "http://192.168.1.6:30032/wd/hub" ;
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);
    }
    }
    
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void Moda()
    {
    try
    {
    //Navigate to URL
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e);
    return;
    }
    
    
    // Close login modal screen
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']")).click();
    
    // Hover the menu Electronics >> MI
    WebElement men1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='Wbt_B2 _1YVU3_'][1]"));
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);      
    act.moveToElement(men1).perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    
    WebElement men2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='_1KCOnI _3ZgIXy'][1]//a[contains(@href,'Electronics_0_Mi')]")); 
    men2.click();
    
    //Verify 'Latest from MI' label on the search result page
    try
    {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ie){
    System.out.println("Error at line 76") ;
    }
    boolean Validate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Latest from MI : ']")).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("Latest from MI element is displayed--" + Validate);
    System.out.println("Completed.") ;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that your test expects to have `System` parameter value in your `testng.xml` file. You have to either add one or add `@Optional` annotation to your method parameter so that the parameter would have been set to that optional value if no values are detected in `testng.xml`.

See details [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters).

Comment: ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="GRID Testing" parallel="tests">
  <test name="pc1">
   <parameter name="System" value="pc1"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="module8.gridTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
  <test name="pc2">
   <parameter name="System" value="pc2"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="module8.gridTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite> <!-- Suite -->``` System exists in grid.xml how to check if grid is working correctly ?

Comment: I do not know what `grid.xml` is. It is not a standard `testng` name. You need to contact the person who provided you the code. I believe it is an custom `testng.xml` but you need to override the default path to your custom one. This can be done when you run tests with maven but I do not know how to customize it in IDE.